# Android SDK Installed, but adb.exe Missing

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

After my [Visual Studio install suddenly lost the ability to deploy my Xamarin app to an android emulator](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55415/error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object#latest), I decided to uninstall EVERYTHING (Visual Studio, Xamarin, Android SDK) and start over.

Everything has been re-installed, but the Android SDK does not include the adb.exe file.  The place where I expect to find it is here:

> C:\Users\costcopc\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

What went wrong?  How can I fix this?

I opened a cmd.exe prompt and searched the entire drive (C:>) to find the file - it doesn't exist.

## Re-Tracing My Steps

In case it helps, I will retrace my steps...

### Uninstalling

I un-installed Xamarin first, [according to instructions](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/uninstalling_xamarin/).  I wanted a blank slate so, per those instructions, I also uninstalled:

- Android SDK Tools
- GTK#

I did not uninstall the Java SDK because, as my very first link explained, I had already used a system restore point to recover a stable version of the Java SDK.

Next up was Visual Studio.  I used its installer for the uninstallation, and then I followed the [post-uninstall "Secondary installer" instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3016536) it gave.

### Re-Installing

I re-installed VS 2015 first, then I launched the Xamarin Studio installer, which in turn installed the Android SDK for me:

[image]

With everything seemingly installed successfully, I launched Visual Studio and tried to open the Android SDK Manager with Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager.

It worked, but I noticed that a cmd.exe window opened and remained opened, **containing a couple strange error messages.**

[image]

There it is: "The process cannot access the file because it is in use by another process."

Despite the anomalies, I did use the SDK manager to install 4 more packages.

Still, I was feeling uneasy about the error messages so I figured it was time to reboot.  After the reboot the situation became worse.  Before, Visual Studio was at least able to launch the android SDK manager.  Now it was altogether unable to launch it:

[image]

That oddball SDK path `C:\Users\costcopc\AppData\Local\Android\ANDROI-1` had disappeared!

Xamarin Studio was also unable to launch the SDK Manager:

[image]

Now I chose to execute a Xamarin Studio installation "repair."  Xamarin acted like the Android SDK was installed, and so it did nothing to fix it.

**Again, what can I do to fix this?**

Comment: Try downloading the sdk separately and then point Xamarin to it using that browse button next to location. Also check your path environment variable if it has any info on the sdk location, and change it if necessary.

Comment: The path environment var is clean.  Also, I followed your advice.  I uninstalled Xamarin and Android SDK (AGAIN) and downloaded Android SDK to install in isolation.  This brought back the adb.exe, but has left me right back where I started: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55415/error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object#latest

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by selecting Tools/Xamarin Account in VS 2017RC.

Then the browser opens, go into your account and download and install Xamarin from here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you installing VS 2015 community ISO from here:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615448&clcid=0x409

after installation, open VS > tools> options > Xamarin , and check that your 
SDK is detected successfully:
[image]

If something is not detected, then run android SDK manager as administrator then make sure that the SDKs are installed/updated correctly.

Answer (score -1):

just Run visual studio as administrator and it will be solved(map directory up to end folder where actual tool are residing)